# How to build libVLC.aar library?

Tags: android, apk, libvlc, aar

I am trying to run this demo [LibVLC on Android demo](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample) project which uses libVLC for android.

So i tried to build the vlc library by following the steps mentioned here [VLC for Android](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/) but i finished with getting an apk file and not an aar file.

Can anyone tell what i am messing here ?

Thanks!

**here is my build.gradle file :**

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to         all sub-projects/modules.
 buildscript {
      repositories {
          flatDir dirs: "gradle/plugins"
           jcenter()
     }
      dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
          classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
          classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    }
 }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
         maven {
             url 'https://maven.google.com'
             // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
         }
         jcenter()
     }
 }

  ext {
      appCompatVersion = '25.2.0'
      constraintLayoutVersion = '1.1.0-beta1'
      buildToolsVersion = "26.0.1"
      compileSdkVersion = 26
      minSdkVersion = 9
     targetSdkVersion = 26
     versionName = '2.5.5'
     versionCode = 2050500
  //    versionCode scheme is T M NN RR AA
  //    T: Target/Flavour (1 for Android, 2 for Chrome?)
  //    M: Major version from 0 to 9
  //    NN: Minor version from 00 to 99
  //    RR: Micro/Revision version from 00 to 99
  //    AA: ABI from 0 to 99
  //    0 is dev
  //    1 was ARMv5        (deprecated)
  //    2 was ARMv6-nofpu  (deprecated)
  //    3 was ARMv6-fpu    (deprecated)
  //    4 is ARMv7-A
  //    5 is x86
  //    6 is MIPS
  //    7 is ARMv8
  //    8 is x86_64
  //    9 is MIPS64
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue with your `gradle` file. because `.aar` file is generated in instead of apk in output folder. Just check your .gradle file by this.

I am using this gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'
    }
}
def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/mengzhidaren'   // 项目的主页

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 20161117
        versionName "1.3.0"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            // Prevent gradle from building native code with ndk; we have our own Makefile for it.
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jni/libs', 'private_libs/libs']
            // Where generated .so files are placed.
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    // Make per-variant version code
//    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
//        variant.outputs.each { output ->
//            def outputFile = output.outputFile
//            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
//                def fileName = "libvlc.aar"
//                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
//            }
//        }
//    }
}
publish {
    userOrg = 'yuyunlongyyl' //用户所在组织
    groupId = 'com.yyl.vlc'// 包名
    artifactId = 'vlc-android-sdk' // library的名字
    publishVersion = '1.3.0'// 版本
    desc = 'vlc-android-lib 2.0.0   2016/10/10  suport x86_64   x86  armeabi-v7a  arm64-v8a   mips   mips64'
    // 描述
    website = siteUrl
}
/*
 * Include GDB files into apk
 */
//afterEvaluate {
//    Sync packageTask = project.getTasks().findByName("packageReleaseJniLibs")
//    packageTask.include(['**/gdbserver', '**/gdb.setup'])
//}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Hi @khemu thanks for your response. I have added the build.gradle file, can take a look and tell me what i have to change exactly ?